# Changing rows color depending on values set from php using ternary operator

Tags: php

I need to change row's color based on values set.
I need to use short notations instead of if-else.
I tried the following :

```
<tr
<?= isset($item['leave_status']) ? echo "style='color:blue;'"; : '' ?>
 >
```

This is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: try <?php echo $item['leave_status'] ? "style='color:blue;'" : '' ?>

Comment: yes... worked perfectly.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr
<?php (isset($item['leave_status'])) ? echo "style='color:blue;'"; : '' ?>
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `<?=` as mentioned in **PHP manual**

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it
>   is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option).

You can read more about here
[PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Instead, you can use

```
<?php
echo isset($item['leave_status']) ? "style='color:blue;'" : '' ;
?>
```

Comment: I also using the full syntax. I never used short tags. Btw i am not a down-voter of your post. I am agreed with you.+1

Answer (score 0):

Remove the echo keyword in the ternary operation

```
<?= isset($item['leave_status']) ? "style='color:blue;'" : '' ;?>

<?= is short for <?php echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, no need for `;` in ternary operations.
And the outcome has to be at the start of the operation (either a variable or an action)

```
<tr
<?php echo (isset($item['leave_status'])) ? "style='color:blue;'" : '' ?>
 >
```